# Momentjs: How can I get correct time from utc date using mixin in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Can anyone point out my mistake?

dateMixin.js
`

```
import moment from 'moment'

export const dateMixin = {
  methods: {
    convertDate (date, format) {
      return moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format(format)
    }
  }
}
```

`

component.vue
here `date = 2019-06-11T15:28:07.226938-07:00`

`

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ convertDate(date, 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A') }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { dateMixin } from '../mixins/dateMixin.js'
export default {
  mixins: [dateMixin]
}
</script>
```

`
Current output: 06/11/2019 12:00 AM
Expected output: 06/11/2019 03:28 PM

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hard-coded the parsing format in your mixin (`'YYYY-MM-DD'`), on this line:

```
return moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format(format)
```

Which reads the first part of your date string (`2019-06-11T15:28:07.226938-07:00`) as `YYYY-MM-DD` and disregards the rest. If you remove the parsing format string and allow moment to read the entire date, i.e:

```
return moment(date).format(format)
```

...it will output correctly. See it working:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#hook',
  template: '#appTemplate',
  data: () => ({
    date: '2019-06-11T15:28:07.226938-07:00'
  }),
  computed: {
    getTimezone() {
      return moment.tz.guess();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    convertDate(date, format) {
      return moment(this.date).format(format)
    },
    convertToUtc(date, format) {
      return moment(this.date).utc().format(format)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
dl { font-family: monospace; }
dd { margin-bottom: 1rem; }
dt { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.25/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/template" id="appTemplate">
  <div id="app">
    <dl>
      <dt v-text="getTimezone"></dt>
      <dd v-text="convertDate(date, 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A')"></dd>
      <dt v-text="`UTC`"></dt>
      <dd v-text="convertToUtc(date, 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A')"></dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</script>
<div id="hook"></div>
```

Otherwise it will read only the date, and default the time to `00:00:00.000000` (which is why you're seeing `12:00 AM`).

Comment: Thanks! that worked. And thanks for explaining...makes more sense now :)